# WPF Binding data in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть Contractor.xaml с DataContext:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Есть ContractorDetail.xaml с DataContext:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ContractWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

В первом окне отображается общая информация, во втором выводятся все поля с возможностью редактирования, переход осуществляется так (Передаётся выбранный Contractor):

```
public void OpenContractorDetailView(object param)
    {
        var contractor = param is ContractorType ? param as ContractorType : null;
        if(contractor != null)
        {
            var contractorDetailsView = new ContractorDetailsWindow();
            var vm = contractorDetailsView.DataContext is ContractorDetailsWindowViewModel ? contractorDetailsView.DataContext as ContractorDetailsWindowViewModel : null;
            vm.Contractor = contractor;

            contractorDetailsView.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            contractorDetailsView.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            contractorDetailsView.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Кнопка Детали создается в code behind Contractor.xaml.cs вот код:

```
var vm = this.DataContext is PackageWindowViewModel ? this.DataContext as PackageWindowViewModel : null;
        var messageType = vm.MessageType;
        foreach(var contractor in messageType.Contractors)
        {
        ...
           Button ownerDetails = new Button()
                {
                    Content = "Детали...",
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 23,
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 5, 0),
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
                    Command = new RelayCommand(arg => vm.OpenContractorDetailView(contractor), can => true)
                };
         ...
```

В итоге, когда я редактирую в поля в модальном окне, они меняются и в главном окне.

Привязка в ContractorDetail сделана так (В примере одно поле объекта Contractor, остальные поля привязаны так же):

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding Path=Contractor.OKTMO, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="2" />
```

Кнопка Save:

```
<Button Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Content="Сохранить" Width="100" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0, 10, 120, 0" Command="{Binding SaveContractorCommad, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Команда SaveContractorCommad привязана к методу: SaveContractorMethod

```
private void SaveContractorMethod()
{
    //OnPropertyChanged("Contractor");
}
```

ViewModel со свойством и полем в ContractWindowViewModel:

```
private ContractorType _contractor;

public ContractorType Contractor
{
    get { return _contractor; }
    set
    {
        _contractor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Contractor");
    }
}
```

Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы при изменения значения полей объекта Contractor через TextBox, эти изменения применялись только по нажатии на кнопку Save, а при отмене или закрытии окна ничего не происходило?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, сделайте для нужных полей свою отдельную VM, и привязывайтесь к ней. А по нажатию `Save` перенесите данные из этой новой VM в основную.

В вашем случае это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
var temporaryContractor = contractor.Clone(); // (*)

var vm = (ContractorDetailsWindowViewModel)contractorDetailsView.DataContext;
vm.Contractor = temporaryContractor;

var contractorDetailsView = new ContractorDetailsWindow()
{
    Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow,
    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner
};
bool? dialogResult = contractorDetailsView.ShowDialog();

if (dialogResult == true) // нужна явная проверка, т. к. может быть false или null
    contractor.LoadFrom(temporaryContractor); // (*)
```

Вам нужно будет ещё дописать два метода, упомянутые в строках, обозначенных `(*)`. Первый метод должен создавать копию объекта, второй должен забирать свойства у этой копии.

```
class ContractorType
{
    // текущий код класса

    public ContractorType Clone()
    {
        return new ContractorType()
        {
            OKTMO = OKTMO,
            // ну и остальные тут же
        };
    }

    public void LoadFrom(ContractorType another)
    {
        OKTMO = another.OKTMO;
        // и т. д.
    }
}
```

Ну или вы можете сэкономить на втором методе, если в случае успеха просто подмените `contractor` в том месте, откуда он берётся, на новый. Но для этого нужно как-то его протянуть в ту точку.

Comment: У меня два окна. Одно с общей информацией а второе для редактирования всех полей, которое открывается в модальном окне. Сейчас у меня при редактировании в модальном окне меняются значения в главном. А нужно сделать чтобы они менялись при сохранении. Сейчас у меня уже два разных vm

Comment: @endovitskiiy: Значит, у вас значения из второй VM используются в главном окне каким-то образом. Или какая-то другая ошибка, но вы ж не дали код, чтобы было понятно, в чём проблема. Приходится угадывать.

Comment: Немного изменил текст вопроса, может теперь понятнее.

Comment: @endovitskiiy: Окей, уже лучше, а как именно вы вызываете `OpenContractorDetailView`? Откуда берётся параметр?

Comment: @endovitskiiy: И кстати, `param is ContractorType ? param as ContractorType : null;` можно свернуть до просто `param as ContractorType` по идее.

Comment: @endovitskiiy: А ещё, вы почему-то устанавливаете `DataContext` прямо в XAML, это обычно не очень правильно (и из-за этого вам приходится изощряться с `var vm = ...; vm.Contractor = contractor;`. Можно было бы проще: `new ContractorDetailsWindow() { DataContext = contractor, Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow, WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner }.ShowDialog();` Но это на будущее.

Comment: Добавил описание кода кнопки. За объяснения спасибо.

Comment: @endovitskiiy: Написал, смотрите.

Comment: смотрю. Сейчас пробую

Comment: Я в классе ContractorType реализовал интерфейс ICloneable, метод **Clone**: **return this.MemberwiseClone()** - вроде работает; Так его использую: Command = new RelayCommand(arg => vm.OpenContractorDetailView(**contractor.Clone()**), can => true) Теперь, конечно в главном окне поля не меняются, что делать дальше не пойму.

Comment: @endovitskiiy: А вы передавайте не клон, а оригинал. А клонируйте внутри. (Ну и вообще попробуйте в точности как в ответе.)